# Singleton function description

Tags: java, android

I searched but didn't find any normal information for Java Singleton functions or classes , So can anybody explain why I need them? What is he difference from other functions?

Comment: You must have been looking for singleton pattern

Comment: check these [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+singleton+class), I never heard concept of singleton function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sometimes it's appropriate to have exactly one instance of a class: window managers, print spoolers, and filesystems are prototypical examples. Typically, those types of objects—known as Singletons`

There is nothing like `Singleton function` , we usually use `Singleton Classes`

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=46

Answer (score 3):

Singleton pattern is used for classes that should only exist by one instance. The purpose of the singleton and its values should be consistent throughout the entire application.

Singletons are commonly used for special environment variables, database connections, factories and object pools.

Answer (score 2):

Singleton is used to create only one instance of the Object

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton uniqueInstance;

    // other stuff
    private Singleton()
    {

    }
    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        if(uniqueInstance == null)
        {
            uniqueInstance = new Singleton();
        }
        return uniqueInstance;
    }
    // other methods
}
```

This is the simple example to make you aware og the singleton pattern

Answer (score 1):

ok this classes has only one object. for making a class Singleton, make the constructor     private and define a static method to get the class object like this

```
   public class yourclassname{
   private yourclassname{}
   public static yourclassname getMySongAlarmdb(Context c)
            {
                if (myobject == null){
                    myobject = new yourclassname;
                }
                return myobject;
            }
    }
```